# Visual Studio Code Unity AutoComplete still not working

Tags: unity, c#, ide, visual-studio-code, code-hinting

I am having an issue with Visual Studio Code AutoComplete for Unity.

Some of the autocomplete is working, such as: `void Start()`, `void Update()`, but most of the rest of Unity Autocomplete is not working such as: `GameObject`, `Rigidbody`, `Input.GetKey`, etc..)

I know VScode and Unity are not connected like how Unity and Visual Studio are, but it seems that a lot of people make it work somehow, so I thought it is possible to make it work without much trouble.

- I have the extensions needed to make it work (C#, Unity Tools, Unity Snippets Code etc...)
- I have set vscode as my script editor (Unity -> Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools)
- I installed  .NET Core SDK and .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack
- I tried uninstalling Unity and vscode but that didn't work either...

How can I solve this?

Comment: I just give up...
for anyone out there is having the same problem as I did, just try Visual Studio instead!
I know it's slower than VS Code but you'll get used to it, trying to make VS Code autocomplete work is just pain in the ass. I wasted like 1 or 2 weeks trying to make it work but nothing...
*Admin, should this be an answer ?*

Comment: you can follow the instructions here: https://www.ehforex.com/2022/01/visual-studio-code-auto-complete-with.html

Comment: JetBrains Rider also does the job, although rather pricey.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, please check which version of omnisharph you have installed, the newest version have a problem with the intellisense, try to install an older version of the omnisharph and it will work ! Also try to check if you have the required plugins for Unity.

Comment: It helps to check the console in VS Code - when I set up a new machine recently, I noticed omnisharp was posting errors about not having the right framework/runtime stuff it needed to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following method and it worked:

1. Change in External Tools: Edit -> Preferences :choose " Visual Studio Code"
2. Open file : Assembly-CSharp-Editor in your project folder and Download the Framework Version that is the same as the version in this file EX: v4.7.1
3. Open VScode tool - Settings - >code lens and tick.

Comment: I sometimes find I have to click the "Regenerate Project Files" button after step 1, just a little lower down in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking in the folder view, and click open c# project, that fixes it for me

Comment: Didn't work for me tho D:

Answer (score 0):

- See if visual studio code is installed in Unity package manager.
- In Visual Studio Code, install the following extensions : Debugger for Unity, Unity tools, Unity Code Snippets

Comment: Note that the question explicitly states "I have the extensions needed to make it work (C#, Unity Tools, Unity Snippets Code etc...)"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't installed any .Net, I just installed an older version (1.16.21) of c# extension, I hope this helps